# C# close excel handle after reading xls

Tags: c#, excel

I am attempting to open an xls file, read in several rows of data, form a custom list from data and then close the excel sheet.  This is what I have:

```
InitializeWorkbook(Path);
List<Custom> list = new List<Custom>();

Worksheet wkSht = (Worksheet)workBk.Worksheets[3];

if (wkSht.Name.Equals("Sht3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Range PartNumRange = wkSht.get_Range("A:A", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    Range RevRange = wkSht.get_Range("C:C", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    Range SwRange = wkSht.get_Range("L:L", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    Range NomenRange = wkSht.get_Range("M:M", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

    // Start at Row 6
    int i = 6;
    object Num = (PartNumRange[i, 1] as Range).Text;
    object Nomen = (NomenRange[i, 1] as Range).Text;
    object Sw = (SwRange[i, 1] as Range).Text;
    object SwRev = (RevRange[i, 1] as Range).Text;

    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Num.ToString()) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Nomen.ToString()) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sw.ToString()) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SwRev.ToString()))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Nomen.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sw.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SwRev.ToString())
        {
            Custom item = new Custom();

            item.PartNumber = (PartNumRange[i, 1] as Range).Text.ToString();
            item.Nomenclature = (NomenRange[i, 1] as Range).Text.ToString();
            item.SwNumber = (SwRange[i, 1] as Range).Text.ToString();
            item.SwRevision = (RevRange[i, 1] as Range).Text.ToString();

            list.Add(item);
        }

        i++;
        Num = (PartNumRange[i, 1] as Range).Text;
        Nomen = (NomenRange[i, 1] as Range).Text;
        Sw = (SwRange[i, 1] as Range).Text;
        SwRev = (RevRange[i, 1] as Range).Text;
    }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(PartNumRange);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(RevRange);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(SwRange);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(NomenRange);

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wkSht);
    workBk.Close(false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBk);

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkSheets);

    ExcelApp.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

I dont know why but Excel is not closing after I finish executing.  Only when the program exits does Excel exit.  I have tried all sorts of combinations and have avoided the two dot rule but still a no go.  Any ideas on what I'm missing?

EDIT:  Calling ExcelApp.Quit closes both ExcelApp and ExcelWorksheets.

Comment: Believe me, I walked the Excel automation way (two dot rule, marshal release and all), then I discovered Flexcel, and I never looked back. You might consider this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this post: [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp)

There's a lot of in-depth discussions about handling COM objects in C# that you might find helpful. Worth a read.

Comment: The question linked above is very good.  In fact, an answer there maybe the same problem: workBk.Worksheets[3] is creating a wrapper around the Worksheets COM Object.

Comment: Rich, that was it.  There was a few other things I had noticed in the API I was using (that had InitializeWorkbook and CloseExcel methods in it) to control Excel that were also doing the same thing (like ExcelApp.Workbook.Open()) so I had fixed those and everything is working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to call close on

- ExcelWorkSheets
- ExcelApp

Calling Marshal.ReleaseComObject disposes the runtime callable wrapper, but leaves the application itself still alive and kicking.

Comment: ExcelApp.Quit closes ExcelApp and ExcelWorkSheets, sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - it's work fine

```
while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(YourRange) > 0) 
{}

while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(YourWorkSheet) > 0) 
{}

while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(YourWorkBook) > 0) 
{}

YourApplication.quit()

while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(YourApplication) > 0) 
{}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it Excel is still running.  I have updated the OP with an update.

Comment: @dangerisgo  add while to your code in order to clean all instance, i had the same problem, i resolved with while;;;; But you can delete  GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();